# Mount disk to /home or /usr in GCP vms

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-image-search

I had question regarding mounting disk on GCP vms and creating logical volumes :

1. **Is is possible to use LVM or create logical volumes (lv) for additional disk and mount it to root folders in gcp images as its breaking the whole VMs down when restarted.
   In other words, create lv at /home or /usr or /var folders for secondary disk attached /dev/sdb**

Is it limitation on GCP Images ?

Comment: Google Cloud disk images are created from a single persistent disk. If you create an LVM that consists of multiple disks, make sure you shut down the VM first before creating images. However, most of the benefits of LVM are negated in HyperVisors and the cloud. Now disks and file systems can be resized effortlessly, SSD performance is very high, etc. Given the management headaches, backup issues, and disaster recovery challenges, carefully consider if you want to deploy LVM in the cloud.

Comment: For the issue in your question, yes you can use LVM for just about any folder provided that the single-user mode of the kernel does not require that file system mounted. Home yes, var I am not sure. Provided that you have the correct mount entries in fstab, update your question to show what you have configured and what errors/issues are occurring. You will need to be detailed.

Comment: Note: Your question is probably better suited for one of the other Stack Exchange sites as this is not a programming or software development question.

Answer (score 0):

LVM is not supported for predefined images on GCP but will work for custom images. It is recommended to create secondary disk instead or simply resize the current disk for additional resources as a workaround.

Please see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#lvm_for) for more information.